# how to make spring mvc 4 and angular run in WebSphere 8

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, websphere

I have an application which runs perfectly on TomCat 8 but it crashes when deployed to Websphere Liberty 8.5.

The first Websphere error was org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl missed then I added tiles dependency even though the application doesn't use tiles as far as I can see. After I added tiles dependency, the error message desapear but the application keeps crashed in Websphere. I can open the well-come page (an Angular table) but when I clicked in Add nothing happens. I don't get an error message in Eclipse console as well (I am debuging it).

All application can be downloaded from here http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/ (future readers might take advantage to know that I have to fix two issues in such example before running in Eclipse: 1 Open the Navigator view, expand the .settings folder, open the file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and manually set the Java version and jst.web 2 Add compile java version in pom.xml).

I could add the entire applcation here but I understand there is nothing wrong with such application otherwise it wouldn't run in Tomcat 8. Probably I am missing something related to Websphere. I am using war because I am sure that Websphere Liberty Profile accepts war (Production versions only accept EAR)

So my straight question: what must I do in order to run Spring MVC 4 + Angular in Websphere 8 with Java 7? (Please don't compare server options: I must use Websphere or give up of any no Websphere compliance framework)

I remenber sometime ago facing certain issue with json functionalities in websphere and it was fixed after added some feature but I don't remenber exactly which one and that case there wasn't Angular at all.

A last comment, I installed certain Angular Extension in Chrome and it shows property undefined. I read answers around but I don't think they are related to my scenario. I am almost sure that there must be some extra configuration/plugin/jar/etc missed in Websphere.

Error in Scope Inspector (Chrome)

```
"Cannot read property '__proto__' of undefined"
stack
:
(...)
get stack
:
get stack()
set stack
:
set stack()
__proto__
:
Error
```

server.xml

```
<server description="new server">
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
    <webApplication id="Spring4MVCAngularJSExample" location="Spring4MVCAngularJSExample.war" name="Spring4MVCAngularJSExample"/>
    <httpSession idLength="28"></httpSession>
</server>
```

Features of Websphere Liberty 8.5 Java EE 7 (wlp-javaee7-8.5.5.9). It is showed when right-clicked in websphere and then clicked in Product Info:

```
appClientSupport-1.0 [1.0.0]
appSecurity-2.0 [1.0.0]
appSecurityClient-1.0 [1.0.0]
batch-1.0 [1.0.0]
beanValidation-1.1 [1.0.0]
bluemixUtility-1.0 [1.0.0]
cdi-1.2 [1.0.0]
collectiveMember-1.0 [1.0.0]
concurrent-1.0 [1.0.0]
distributedMap-1.0 [1.0.0]
ejb-3.2 [1.0.0]
ejbHome-3.2 [1.0.0]
ejbLite-3.2 [1.0.0]
ejbPersistentTimer-3.2 [1.0.0]
ejbRemote-3.2 [1.0.0]
el-3.0 [3.0.0]
federatedRegistry-1.0 [1.0.0]
j2eeManagement-1.1 [1.1.0]
jacc-1.5 [1.0.0]
jaspic-1.1 [1.0.0]
javaMail-1.5 [1.5.0]
javaee-7.0 [7.0.0]
javaeeClient-7.0 [1.0.0]
jaxb-2.2 [1.0.0]
jaxrs-2.0 [1.0.0]
jaxrsClient-2.0 [1.0.0]
jaxws-2.2 [1.0.0]
jca-1.7 [1.0.0]
jcaInboundSecurity-1.0 [1.0.0]
jdbc-4.1 [1.0.0]
jndi-1.0 [1.0.0]
jpa-2.1 [1.0.0]
jsf-2.2 [1.0.0]
json-1.0 [1.0.0]
jsonp-1.0 [1.0.0]
jsp-2.3 [1.0.0]
ldapRegistry-3.0 [1.0.0]
localConnector-1.0 [1.0.0]
managedBeans-1.0 [1.0.0]
mdb-3.2 [1.0.0]
monitor-1.0 [1.0.0]
requestTiming-1.0 [1.0.0]
restConnector-1.0 [1.0.0]
servlet-3.1 [1.0.0]
sessionDatabase-1.0 [1.0.0]
ssl-1.0 [1.0.0]
wasJmsClient-2.0 [1.0.0]
wasJmsSecurity-1.0 [1.0.0]
wasJmsServer-1.0 [1.0.0]
webCache-1.0 [1.0.0]
webProfile-7.0 [7.0.0]
websocket-1.1 [1.0.0]
```

Pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <finalName>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Spring Configurations:

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Spring Initializer:

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter() };
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

**** Edited in 02/May/2016 at 10PM Brazilia time

I was guessing the issue was about some missed configuration related to websphere, so I tried:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Nevertheless, none of them was the issue. Sily as it can be, I didn't note that there was some hard code port number on it.

```
App.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return {
            fetchAllUsers: function() {
                    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/')
...
```

Hopefully, it can be one day be usefull to someone. 
To sum up, there is nothing wrong with default features of Websphere Liberty Profile. I didn't note some hard code port numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?

Comment: If I deploy the application to TomCat, I can open the wellcome page with the table filled in with 3 sample lines. Then I click in Add button to add a new line and it works (e.g. new line is added to the table). If I deploy it to Websphere, I see the wellcome page with none of the previous lines. Plus that, when I click in Add button nothing happens. I look at Eclipse Console and Websphere Logs and there is no error at all. I inspect the page by using certain Chrome Extension and then I see "Cannot read property '__proto__' of undefined". My best guess is that Websphere miss a feature/settup

Comment: I suspect no one will be able to help unless you're able to narrow the problem down to the specific difference between the two application servers.  But as a wild guess, have you tried unzipping your .war to a directory rather than setting the location to the .war file?  (Note also that "I understand there is nothing wrong with such application otherwise it wouldn't run in Tomcat 8" is not necessarily a true statement.)

Comment: Covener and Brett, thanks for you time and effort. Unfortunatelly, I was going in a very wrong direction. I added my comments. Maybe it can be usefull to someone trying to use Angular and Spring MVC in Websphere Liberty Profile.

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved? I am having similar issues where I am not able to do requests by doing URL rewrite to index.html when using routes. The application breaks with page not found error. Is there a configuration to do a URL rewrite in websphere?